# Drupal 7 node save gives intermittent token validation error

Tags: forms, tokens

When submitting a content type node I'm occasionally seeing a form validation error regarding tokens being invalid.

I've tried reducing the token tree depth too using [Token Tweaks](https://www.drupal.org/project/token_tweaks) which helps on token list viewing, but makes no different on form submission and validation process.

What other causes could be at play with the form token validation flow in Drupal 7 ?

Comment: Invalid token error message in a form means that the security token inlcuded in the form is not valid. So it's not related to tokens provided by Token module (is another kind of token). What's the exact error message you see?

Comment: Example of the errors:

The Page title is using the following invalid tokens: [node:title], [site:name].
The Description is using the following invalid tokens: [node:summary].

Comment: Sorry, then it's related to Token mdoule, I had the form security token in mind.